# ClassCastException while looking up Websphere ConnectionFactory via JNDI

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, websphere

I am getting the following class-cast exception.
It is probably occurring because my application is using `JMS 2.0` APIs whereas `Websphere 8.5.x` is returning `JMS v1.x` compatible object

Is it `Websphere 8.5.x` limitations? What can I change on Websphere and/or application so it both return / use javax.jms.ConnectionFactory object?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryHandle incompatible with javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
    at com.mypackage.myclass.MyConfig.getConnectionFactory(MyConfig.java:152)
```

Websphere suggests to use `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` object which I am already using but still getting the above exception.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21238470

**Code:**

```
conFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiLookup(jndiConnetionFctoryPath);
```

**Stacktrace is:**

```
[Message] Application startup failed
<log4j:throwable><![CDATA[org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'createJmsTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [MyConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'createJmsTransactionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/_tech/mypackage/config/JmsIbmMQConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'getConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryHandle incompatible with javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:619)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:409)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:170)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1178)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1383)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:972)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:777)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2197)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5486)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2202)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:984)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/_tech/mypackage/config/JmsIbmMQConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'getConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryHandle incompatible with javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'getConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryHandle incompatible with javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryHandle incompatible with javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
    at com._tech.mypackage.config.JmsIbmMQConfig.getConnectionFactory(JmsIbmMQConfig.java:152)
    at com._tech.mypackage.config.JmsIbmMQConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$64725c70.CGLIB$getConnectionFactory$3(<generated>)
    at com._tech.mypackage.config.JmsIbmMQConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$64725c70$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3cf0b043.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at com._tech.mypackage.config.JmsIbmMQConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$64725c70.getConnectionFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 59 more
]]></log4j:throwable>
```

Comment: What is `jndiLookup()`?

Comment: @EJP: Open Declaration Object javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(String name) throws NamingException

Retrieves the named object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSphere 8.5 only supports JMS 1.x. Most likely what is happening is you are doing a JNDI lookup of a JMS object that is managed by the application server which is at JMS 1.x. Your application is probably configured with JMS 2.0 classes and to load those in preference to the JMS 1.x version from the application and on lookup because of this you can't do the conversion. to a compatible type. If you need JMS 2.0 then you should be using WebSphere 9.

Comment: I am using WebSphere 9.0.5.2, still having same issue. My code is:
return (ConnectionFactory) initContext.lookup(jndiName);

And I am getting following error in WebSphere:
nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSTopicConnectionFactoryHandle incompatible with javax.jms.ConnectionFactory